# Google Custom Search API adding annotations programmatically through php via cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, google-custom-search

I'm trying to add annotations (sites to search) to my google custom search engine programmatically by POSTing xml using php and cURL.  According to their developer documentation, all I need to do is:

```
POST http://www.google.com/cse/api/default/annotations/
Content-Type: text/xml
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="IM6F7Cx2fo0TAiwlhNVdSE8Ov8hw6aHV"

<Batch>
<Add>
<Annotations>
  <Annotation about="http://www.solarenergy.org/*">
    <Label name="_cse_solar_example"/>
  </Annotation>
  <Annotation about="http://www.solarfacts.net/*">
    <Label name="_cse_solar_example"/>
  </Annotation>
  <Annotation about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*">
    <Label name="_cse_exclude_solar_example"/>
  </Annotation>

  </Annotations>
  </Add>
  </Batch>
```

However, when I use the following code, I get an error 411, "POST requests require a Content-length header"

```
function getAuthorizationToken(){
$ch = curl_init();
$url = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE&Email=***&Passwd=***&service=cprose&source=***';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
$authTokenData = curl_exec($ch);
$authTokenArray = explode('Auth=', $authTokenData);
$authToken = $authTokenArray[1];
curl_close($ch);
return $authToken;
}

$authToken = getAuthorizationToken();

$url = 'http://www.google.com/cse/api/default/annotations/';
$xml_data = '<?XML version="1.0"?>
<Batch>
  <Add>
    <Annotations>
      <Annotation about="http://www.solarenergy.org/*">
        <Label name="_cse_solar_example"/>
      </Annotation>
      <Annotation about="http://www.solarfacts.net/*">
        <Label name="_cse_solar_example"/>
      </Annotation>
      <Annotation about="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*">
        <Label name="_cse_exclude_solar_example"/>
      </Annotation>
     </Annotations>
  </Add>
</Batch>';
$length = strlen($xml_data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=".        $authToken, "Content-Type: text/xml", "Content-Length: " . $length));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // ask for results to be returned
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I've been struggling with this issue for a very long time, and I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to send annotations to `http://www.google.com/cse/api/default/annotations/solar_example` and remove `Content-Length` header from curl options. It should looks like this:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array(
    "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=". $authToken, 
    "Content-Type: text/xml"
));
```

It works for me.

Comment: Did you possibly change anything else?  It's still not working for me unfortunately after changing my code by your suggestions

Comment: No, I didn't. Everything else seems like the same.